# Remove network drive permissions of a user in all subdirectories

Tags: powershell, cmd, acl, ntfs, icacls

I am trying to remove a user from all subdirectories in a network share.

I have tried the following command: ICACLS X:\ /remove:g username /T

The command runs without failure (although it takes 3.5 hours due to the size of the shard drive) but after I check the permissions, the user's permissions are not deleted from anywhere.

If I navigate to a specific folder where I know that the user has access and run the command there (for example ICACLS X:\subdirectory /remove:g username /T ), it works just fine.

The issue seems to occur only if I try to run it from the root X:\ in which case, no permissions are deleted.

Any ideas why this might be the case?

P.S. I have F access on the root on the account I'm running the command with

Comment: Are all of your folders inheriting from parent?  If so, then the change is never taking effect because the permissions are cascading down your filesystem.  You would need to break the 'inherit-from-parent' flag first, then set your permissions.  I would caution you against unintended consequences though since it seems like it might be a large quantity of files/directories.

Comment: @thepip3r yes, looking at the current permissions it appears that all subfolders are inheriting their permissions from the folders above (most users are (I)(CI)(OI) permissions)

Do you have a different suggestion to delete the user via ICACLS without breaking the "inherit-from-parent" flag?

Would something like granting basic read access at root and then deleting the user at root work?

Answer (score 0):

Should do it with `icacls /T`. Unless the user running the command cannot read some directories. But if inheritance is enabled on the folders you probably have Administrators everywhere.

A simple PS Script can do it. With some try / catch around `$acl | Set-Acl` this can be used as a dry-mode in a non-privileged session. With a privileged session this will effectively replace the ACL on the directory.

```
$path = "X:"
$username = "Domain\User"
Get-Item -Path $path -Directory -Recurse | %{
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $_.FullName
    $aces = $acl.Access | Where-Object { -not $_.IsInherited -and $_.IdentityReference.Value -eq $username }

    if ($aces -ne $null -and $aces.Count -gt 0) {

        Write-Host "Found $($aces.Count) ACE granted for $username on $($_.FullName)"

        foreach($ace in $aces) {
            $acl.RemoveAccessRule($ace)
        }
        $acl | Set-Acl -Path $_.FullName
    }
}
```